# CMake and Latex

Tags: latex, cmake

I am using the [UseLATEX.cmake](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/images/8/80/UseLATEX.cmake) to compile my project documentation folder.

My project is organized as follows --

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── bin
├── build
├── cmake
│   ├── CMakeCompilerFlags.cmake
│   ├── CMakeDefaults.cmake
│   ├── MacroEnsureOutOfSourceBuilds.cmake
│   └── UseLATEX.cmake
├── doc
│   ├── Doc.tex
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── images
│       ├── img1.png
│       ├── img2.png
│       ├── img3.png
│       └── img4.jpeg
............
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── file1.cpp
    ├── file2.cpp
    └── file3.cpp
```

My root level cmake file is like this ...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

# Set path for CMake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake"
    ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
)

# Define project settings
project(proj)
set(APPLICATION_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
include(CMakeDefaults)

# Compile Program and Docs
include_directories(inc)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(doc)
```

And the CMakeList file in the document file is --

```
include(UseLATEX)

ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT(Doc.tex
    #BIBFILES mybib.bib
    IMAGE_DIRS images
    DEFAULT_PDF
)
```

Now I compile my project in the `build` folder. Is there any way I can copy back the `Doc.pdf` file created in the `build/doc` folder back to my original build folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT` adds a CMake target named `pdf` here, you should be able to make use of [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command).  Try adding the following to your `/doc/CMakeLists.txt` *after* the `ADD_LATEX_DOCUMENT` call:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET pdf POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doc.pdf
                       ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Doc.pdf)
```

This custom command invokes the cmake executable (held in the variable `${CMAKE_COMMAND}`) along with the [`-E copy` arguments](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#opt%3a-E) every time the `pdf` target is built.